# Authentication using selenium python and Scanning through OWASP ZAP

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, owasp, zap

I have a website which includes a username and password field. On providing the correct combination a page with a dropdown is displayed.

I am unable to authenticate this using ZAP. Because of this I want to Authenticate using Selenium Python and navigate to the Homepage. I have done the above mentioned on selenium using Python.

I want to run this through ZAP. Please assist me.

Summary:
Unable to authenticate through ZAP
Have a python script to open the browser and login to my page
Want to direct this though ZAP and spider and Active scan it

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can either authenticate yourself (manually or using your own cript) and then pass session details to ZAP or you can configure ZAP to handle the authentication. ZAP includes Selenium so you can use that in ZAP scripts.

See the ADDO Workshop videos on https://www.alldaydevops.com/zap-in-ten - I show how to launch a browser to handle a Google login to OWASP Juice Shop.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have viewed the video and it was helpful. A humble request if you could let me know where I can refer to the scripts used in the video workshop. If possible please do share.